# Add more beta testers for the app through crashlytics beta

Tags: ios, crashlytics, beta-testing

If I have to add more testers (especially outside clients), What is the best way to add it?

Since I don't know the outside testers' UDID, how do I tackle this situation? The only way I can see is request their UDIDs and add them to the profile, download the updated profile and rebuild it and send it to these outside testers. Seems very cumbersome.

Comment: That's pretty much it in a nutshell... AFAIK there's no other way to officially distribute ad hoc builds unless you add them to the provisioning profile.

Comment: If that is the case, what is the value addition that crashlytics or testflight gives? What I mean is, if they provide an easier way to add the UDIDs to the provisioning profile from the device and update the build.

Comment: When it comes to TestFlight, it takes an extra few steps out of distribution because you simply drop the ipa in their portal and it takes care of emailing everyone all at once with release notes. When it comes to crashlytics, they make it EVEN EASIER by allowing you to essentially deploy from Xcode when you archive, without even touching the archive at all, not to mention their fantastic analytics/crash reporting that comes with it for free.

Answer (score 0):

Actually not. But, you can ask users for their UUID before your build and then add them to your developer account and then release the build. Their are few methods you can Google of how users can get their device UUID.

Or you can use Test Flight beta for external users, which requires Email ID of testers only and a beta review from Apple which takes less than 24 hours, if that's not a problem. It also makes sure your app is fit for app store at every iterating and will significantly reduce chances of rejection at final stages.