# Is there a one step method of activating beta testers on iOS using Fabric?

Tags: ios, twitter-fabric, crashlytics-beta

We're using Fabric (Crashlytics) to get our app to beta testers. This is not a utility app, so any friction in the beta distribution/acceptance process is unhelpful.

The process today is:
(1) send an invite
(2) the user accepts the invite, which sends their UUID. You don't get to experience the app at this stage.
(3) another build is created with additional UUIDs etc
(4) the users get a new release emai), which they install, and get to use the app.

Many days can pass between (1) and (4). It takes many reminders to get some folks (understandably busy) to click the second invite ("didn't I do this already?").

Is there a better way? Without an App Store approval process?

Related question, but not satisfying answers: [Add more beta testers for the app through crashlytics beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651078/add-more-beta-testers-for-the-app-through-crashlytics-beta)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.  Stack Overflow is not Fabric Customer Support.

Comment: I'll disagree strongly. Why should SO be "customer support" for iOS and Google and not Fabric? What distinguishes a "how-to" question from "customer support"? And beta-testing is squarely about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only other option is an Enterprise account from Apple, which will let you create an In House provisioning profile which lets people run your app without having to add the UUID. However, there are limitations. [Apple's Enterprise Dev Program homepage.](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/how-it-works/)

Comment: While not what we want to hear, this is _the_ answer it appears. There was also a previous response (now removed?) which recommended using TestFlight Beta, indicating an App Store approval process of "under 24 hours". This may be the approach we take, so wanted to mention it.